# Delete word containing one or more upper case letters

Tags: sed

Hi I'm learning sed and I want to solve one of my exercises. It says that i need to delete any word in the line that contains one or more upper case letters.

Example input:

```
Hi im NEW here need help NOw
```

output:

```
im here need help
```

Comment: What is your effort so far?

Comment: i know how to delete only word that contains all upper case letters but not something like this...

Comment: Show us your code for how to delete a word that has all upper case letters and make we can help from there.

Comment: @user3473968 I have added a `sed` solution, let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
echo Hi im NEW here need help NOw | xargs -n1 | sed '/[A-Z]/d' | xargs
im here need help
```

Comment: +1 lol - brilliant! = anyway, it is not a pure sed... but really nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it in `sed`:

```
$ echo "Hi im NEW here need help NOw" | sed -r ':a;s/[a-z]*[A-Z]+[a-z]* *//;ta'
im here need help
```

Comment: +1 for a pure sed solution; also works properly with tokens containing `'` chars.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0. Not my preferred tool of choice, but I like the challenges it offers sometimes. `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
echo "Hi im NEW here need help NOw" | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i!~/[[:upper:]]/) printf "%s ",$i;print""}'
im here need help
```

This test one and one field.  Print all field not contain any upper case letter.

Comment: the problem is that the question ask to be written in sed

Comment: @user3473968 The response from Mark is not only `sed`. Not all can be easy solved by `sed` or one single command.